# WebView mainFrame method returns nil

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have the following code in a window controller as part of a singleton special web browser

```
+ (id)sharedPurchaseController {
    static SomeController *sharedController = nil;

    if (!sharedController) {
        sharedController = [[SomeController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"anXIB"];
    }

    return sharedController;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{
    shouldReloadWeb = NO;
    [progressIndicator startAnimation:nil];
    NSString* urlText = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
}

-(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification{
    shouldReloadWeb = YES;
}

- (void)windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification{
        if (shouldReloadWeb){
        WebFrame* aFrame = [webView mainFrame]; //<-- Returns nil second time
        [[webView mainFrame] reload];
        shouldReloadWeb = NO;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the NSWindow (browser) is closed and then re-open, for a second time, `[webView mainFrame]` returns nil. The NSWindow appears on screen, but the WebView is non-responsive.

If I comment out the code that creates a singleton, everything works as expected.

Is there away to create a singleton browser with an application while keeping the WebView in the Nib?

Thanks, -Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a `WebView` is closed when its container window is closed. When a `WebView` is closed, it unloads the current page, stops loading any current requests and no longer processes new requests nor sends delegate messages. If you want the `WebView` to stick around so it can be reused when the window is reopened, you should call

```
[webView setShouldCloseWithWindow:NO];
```

in your `-awakeFromNib` method.